# regex replacing URL for image file extension; replace spaces with plus

Tags: java, regex

I am learning regex and am looking to search a url for any possible image extension (jpg, jpeg, png, gif .. etc) AND if the file extension of the URL is an image.

I want to replace any `%20` or spaces with plus signs `+`

How can this be done?

```
www.test.com/this/is/an/image&20with%20spaces.jpg 
www.test.com/this/is/an/image+with+spaces.jpg
```

Comment: Does the URL have to end with your extension? i.e. How about `example.com/getImg/foo.png/thumb`

Comment: Yes the URL must end in the original extension

Comment: Is it necessary that solution should be regex based beacuse you can use `String.endsWith` to check for file extension and than use `String.replaceAll` for the substitution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to do this in two lines, the way I see it.

```
Pattern imagePattern = Pattern.compile("\\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
if (imagePattern.matcher(input).find())
  input = input.replaceAll("(%20)|\\s", "+");
```